# Create a custom page in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I am new to Sitefinity and looking for a solution to create a custom password protected page that prompts used first with a password form and if successful, would display the content on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a standard functionality of the CMS - just create the page and then from the Actions menu select Set Permissions and there you can set that only Authenticated users (or any other role) can have View access to the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not CMS users. In the page, I have a text field that contains the password and when the user first hit this page, I will have a password form that checks the password from CMS and if its valued, they see the content

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the requirement, but it sounds like a bad idea. Feel free to provide more details

Comment: With the COVID, one of my clients has requested a password protected page which would contain some embedded videos that need to be shared with school teachers. I am new to Sitefinity and used to Episerver where we usually build a custom page that includes a property for the CMS user to enter the password and in the view, we have an if-else condition to show the password first and once authenticated, it shows the content. Not the secure way but that's something some of my non-profit clients are requesting for recently

Comment: My answer is still valid - page is not going to be accessible to anonymous users. If they try to access it, they will be redirected to /login?ReturnUrl=yourSecurePageUrl ... /login is a front-end login page (not the backend login).

Comment: I ran into any other issue following your setup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616955/users-redirected-to-back-end-login-inseated-of-front-end-login-widget-for-a-re