# Users redirected to Back-end Login inseated of Front end (Login widget) for a restricted page

Tags: sitefinity

I have updated the access permission for a page to be "Authenticated" and set the FrontEndLoginPageId and FrontEndLoginPageUrl in Default settings and Also enabled "AuthenticateOnFrontendLoginPage" in Advanced setting security section but still getting redirected to Backend login, any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you put the correct FrontEndLoginPageId ? Better leave it as empty Guid and just use the FrontEndLoginPageUrl. Also, do you have multisite module enabled?

Comment: I have multi-site module disabled and I will try it with just the url

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I was able to get it to work. I cannot access Backend login page anymore. Does that mean I have to go through the Front End Login even for Admin ?